# non trivial android fragments backstack

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to implement the following fragment design:
Fragment A is replaced by fragment B, which in turn, is replaced by fragment C.
Whether in fragment B or C, I want the user back navigation to take it back to fragment A.
I add to backstack when replacing A with B. But when I move from B to C, I don't add to backstack.
When navigating back from fragment B, everything works fine.
But, when navigating back from C, I get A and C on the same screen - C doesn't disappear.
I wonder if it is related to my backstack usage.
Any help is appreciated.

My code is equivalent to:

```
Fragment fragment;

fragment = new FragmentA();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

fragment = new FragmentB();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

fragment = new FragmentC();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general way to add to Backstack. Use tags.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1, Fragment1.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment1.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now similarly, for frament2:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, Fragment2.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Fragment2.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Do the same for fragment3.
And now you remove fragment2 from backstack using:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(
    Fragment2.class.getName(), 
    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

You should be able to skip directly from fragment3 back to fragment2.

Also, are you using fragmentTransaction.replace(...) and not fragmentTransaction.add(...). Could you post relevant code?

Comment: {{{
My code is equivalent to:
Fragment fragment;

fragment = new FragmentA();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

fragment = new FragmentB();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

fragment = new FragmentC();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
}}}

Comment: The addToBackStack(null) is the main problem, try assigning tags Fragment1.class.getName() as suggested and pop the 2nd fragment out using it's tag. You can then skip from the 3rd fragment directly to the 1st)